# Acknowledging an Exchange calendar response triggers a new invitation

Tags: calendar, exchange

I have Calendar connected to an Exchange 2010 server. I created an event with several (~40) persons. When someone answers I sometimes (not always) have a notification in Calendar with an "OK" button.

If I click "OK" the invitation is sent again to everybody.

I also noticed that sometimes when I snooze an alarm the other invited persons receive a notification per email.

**Edit 1**

This happens with each and every event that I create on Exchange, not only the example above.

**Edit 2**

Is there a way to solve the problem?
Or is there a way to gather more information (for example logs)?

**Edit 3**

I just noticed that when clicking on "OK"

[image]

Calendar sends an email to the attendees (I found it in the "Sent" folder) with the invitation attached (which makes no sense).

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
METHOD:REQUEST
PRODID:Microsoft Exchange Server 2010
VERSION:2.0
BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
TZID:W. Europe Standard Time
BEGIN:STANDARD
DTSTART:16010101T030000
TZOFFSETFROM:+0200
TZOFFSETTO:+0100
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;INTERVAL=1;BYDAY=-1SU;BYMONTH=10
END:STANDARD
BEGIN:DAYLIGHT
DTSTART:16010101T020000
TZOFFSETFROM:+0100
TZOFFSETTO:+0200
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;INTERVAL=1;BYDAY=-1SU;BYMONTH=3
END:DAYLIGHT
END:VTIMEZONE
BEGIN:VEVENT
ORGANIZER;CN=:MAILTO:********
ATTENDEE;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;PARTSTAT=NEEDS-ACTION;RSVP=TRUE;CN=HÃ¤ubi  J
 Ã¼rg A. (ID PPF):MAILTO:********
DESCRIPTION;LANGUAGE=en-US:When: Thursday\, January 29\, 2015 2:00 PM-3:00 
 PM. (UTC+01:00) Amsterdam\, Berlin\, Bern\, Rome\, Stockholm\, Vienna\nWhe
 re: STB H11.1\n\n*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*\n\n\nORIGINAL TEXT\n
SUMMARY;LANGUAGE=en-US:Archivmigration
DTSTART;TZID=W. Europe Standard Time:20150129T140000
DTEND;TZID=W. Europe Standard Time:20150129T150000
UID:484366B6-E758-4B66-B590-E42D1797C805
CLASS:PUBLIC
PRIORITY:5
DTSTAMP:20150123T152428Z
TRANSP:OPAQUE
STATUS:CONFIRMED
SEQUENCE:1
LOCATION;LANGUAGE=en-US:STB H11.1
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-APPT-SEQUENCE:1
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-OWNERAPPTID:2112993755
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-BUSYSTATUS:TENTATIVE
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-INTENDEDSTATUS:BUSY
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-ALLDAYEVENT:FALSE
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-IMPORTANCE:1
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-INSTTYPE:0
X-MICROSOFT-DISALLOW-COUNTER:FALSE
BEGIN:VALARM
ACTION:DISPLAY
DESCRIPTION:REMINDER
TRIGGER;RELATED=START:-PT15M
END:VALARM
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

This does not seem to be generated by Calendar (`PRODID:Microsoft Exchange Server 2010`), it seems that Calendar sends back the confirmation it received.

**Edit 4**

I am using Calendar 8.0 on Yosemite but the problem was already present on Mavericks before the upgrade.

Comment: To narrow down the problem a bit, have you found that the responses from specific people always cause this behavior, or does it appear to occur randomly, with random people? An example would be that a response from user A always triggers this behavior, while a response from user B never does. I'm far from being an Exchange expert at all, but finding a correlation between a user 'out there' and an odd behavior can be helpful in troubleshooting. If there is a correlation, it may be a simple setting on the users' configurations.

Comment: It's not user related. Happens with random persons.

Comment: Oh, well. it was worth a shot. Hope you figure it out.

Comment: Could you check if the Respond was send from iPhone user.

Comment: @Buscar웃 No iPhone involved (I am using OS X and the other users mostly Outlook on Windows). But this is not relevant: Calendar should not send another invitation when clicking on "OK".

Comment: what is not relevant?

Comment: Which client is the recipient using. Calendar sends an email it should not send.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that it was a bug and that it will be fixed with OS X 10.11.0 and iOS 9.

Since the first public beta (on both iOS and OS X) the problem disappeared (without any change on my side).

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem between Microsoft Exchange and your mac. I have had same issue a while ago, and decided not to change stuff via an Apple device.

I know it's not the answer you were hoping for, but's the reality at this moment.

Comment: Not using OS X is as you said not a solution. Also not using the calendar ...

Comment: See the edit: the problem is that Calendar sends an email it should not send. After clicking "OK" it sends an invitation again. Exchange is not even involved.

Answer (score 0):

Heres a long shot in the Calendar.app prefs at the bottom of the `Advanced` pane, do you have checked:

`Ask before sending changes to events`

[image]

From what I understand this prevents messages being sent  other people when you make changes. It may include invitations

Comment: It was checked. It only asks when I actively change something.

Answer (score 0):

I have this exact problem too. Apple Calendar + Office 365 Exchange = spam all your invitees when you are the organizer of an event and you confirm/snooze a notification of an event.

I've stopped using it and rely only on Outlook for Mac instead.